# Why did PERL creators use % to represent Hash Data Structure instead of using the #(hash ) sign?

Tags: perl

why did the perl creators use `%` instead of `#`?

*Right:* =>    %data = ('John Paul', 45, 'Lisa', 30, 'Kumar', 40);

*Wrong:* =>   #data = ('John Paul', 45, 'Lisa', 30, 'Kumar', 40);  (**This could have been a lot simpler to understand  because the # sign is also called HASH  **)

Comment: Because that's what the design said. Probably because though `#` denotes a comment in shell scripts.

Comment: Is there some reason you think it should have been different?  Some problem you're encountering as a result of this?

Comment: @David — Presumably that the pound symbol is also known as the hash sign.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a rather 'why does a language use the syntax like this'... and there's no real answer apart from "because it does".

Comment: @Sobrique: That is simply wrong. Someone made the decision which syntax to use, that someone had reasons for the solution chosen, and listing those reasons here would be a perfect answer to a perfectly valid question. Perhaps the question is off-topic here, but it is a factual question, a good answer to it *is* possible, and it would *not* be opinion-based.

Comment: Perl is Open Source, you are free to download it and alter the code to be whatever you want.  Good luck!

Comment: @akshymane please mark answer as accepted unless there is still an open issue.

Comment: @neuhaus   I dont think it answers the question,  
Im looking at historical perspective of PERL and symbols.

More importantly i dont understand why this question is put on hold :/ :/

Answer (score 3):

> It's a little mnemonic trick to help you remind about the key-value
>   structure.

Source: http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes

Comment: What's the mnemonic?

Comment: There are two numbers in a percent sign, separated by the slash. Think of them as key + value.